# The position of some lists in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists:

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}}
```

I want a list of the positions at which the lists containing no 1's occur.  For the above I want: `{1,6,9,10,11}`.

I have tried `Position[list, x_/;Count[x,1]==0 &]` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This counts how many 1's are in each sublist, and then finds the position of all those with zero count. With `list` equal to your list:

```
Position[Count[#, 1] & /@ list, 0] // Flatten

{1, 6, 9, 10, 11}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]
f1 = MapIndexed[If[FreeQ[#, 1], #2[[1]], ## &[]] &, #] &;
f2 = Pick[Range@Length@#, Times @@@ Unitize[# - 1], 1] &;
f3 = Flatten@Position[Times @@@ Unitize[# - 1], 1] &;


f1@list
```

> {1, 6, 9, 10, 11}

```
Equal @@ (#[list] & /@ {f1, f2, f3} )
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

A logical approach:

```
Flatten @ Position[#, 0] & @ (Boole @ MemberQ[#, 1] & /@ list)
```

or

```
Flatten @ Position[#, 1] & @ (Boole @ Not @ MemberQ[#, 1] & /@ list)
```

> {1, 6, 9, 10, 11}

The first is a bit shorter, but in the second you keep picking "true" statements (due to the `Not`), so it might be cenceptually simpler.

---

Regarding **your own approach**, i.e. `Position[list, x_/;Count[x,1]==0 &]`, it's *almost* right. You mixed patterns and functions. It will work if you delete the `&` sign and specify the level in `Position` to be `1`:

```
Flatten @ Position[list, x_ /; Count[x, 1] == 0, 1]
```

> {0, 1, 6, 9, 10, 11}

Note, however, that you obtain an unnecessary `0` too.

---

Additionally, an approach with `Cases`:

```
Position[list, #] & /@ 
  Cases[list, s_ /; MemberQ[s, 1] == False] // Flatten
```

> {1, 6, 9, 10, 11}

Answer (score 2):

```
Rest@Position[list, a_List /; FreeQ[a, 1], {1}]
Flatten@Rest@Position[list, Except[{___, 1, ___}], {1}]
```

(So that it doesn't get lost, Bob Hanlon's variation:)

```
Rest@Flatten@Position[list, _?(FreeQ[#, 1] &), 1]
```

Comment: `Rest@Flatten@Position[list, _?(FreeQ[#, 1] &), 1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1,
    1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3,
    3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}}

ContainsNone[{1}] /@ list // Position[#, True] & // Flatten

Position[list, _?(ContainsNone[{1}]), 1] // Flatten

list // Map[FreeQ[#, 1] &] // Position[True] // Flatten

list // Map[FreeQ[1]] // Position[True] // Flatten

SequenceCases[#, {___, 1, ___}] & /@ list // Position[{}] // Flatten

Position[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[Except[1] ..]}, 1] // Flatten

Counts /@ list // Map[#[1] &] // Position[_Missing] // Flatten

list // Map[Count[#, 1] &] // Position[0] // Flatten

FirstPosition[#, 1, x] & /@ list // Position[x] // Flatten
```

---

*Result:*

> {1, 6, 9, 10, 11}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 1},
        {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}};
```

---

Using `DeleteCases` and `Position`:

```
patt = Alternatives @@ Permutations[{1, __, _}];

DeleteCases[list, patt] // Map[Position[list, #] &] // Flatten
```

*Result*:

> {1, 6, 9, 10, 11}

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
patt = {___, s : {OrderlessPatternSequence[Except[1] ..]}, ___} :> s;

ReplaceList[list, patt] // Map[Position[list, #] &] // Flatten
```

*Result*:

> {1, 6, 9, 10, 11}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
  {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, 
   {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 1},
   {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}};


Flatten @ Position[list, Alternatives @@ GroupBy[list, FreeQ @ 1][True]]
```

{1, 6, 9, 10, 11}